# React-Typescript: doesn't render component

Tags: typescript, react-query

I have a simple react app that renders a to-do list; I am using Typescript 4.5.4 and reactQuery 3.34.7 for data fetching.

Issue: when I run my app, it does not render any component, and the fetch function only logs undefined.

**App component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery, useQueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
import './App.css';
import List from './components/List';


const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <List />
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**List component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useQuery,
  useQueryClient,
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  UseBaseQueryResult,
} from 'react-query';

interface Props {
  item:
    | {
        title: string;
        completed: string;
      }[];
}

const getTodos = async () => {
  const request = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  return request.json();
};

const List: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { data } = useQuery<Props['item']>('todo', getTodos);
  const renderList = () => {
    console.log('query', data);

    return data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
          <h3>{item.completed}</h3>
        </>
      );
    });
  };
  return <div>{renderList()}</div>;
};

export default List;
```

the data.map highlight with an error message that says

```
const data: {
    title: string;
    completed: string;
}[] | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Comment: how about returning todos by `return await request.json();` ?

Comment: and also consider that when you try to receive just one todo, your data would be an object not array, `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)` will get an array of `todos` and `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1)` will get an todo object which is not an array so you can not map over it.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo thanks man it works! I changed the API so the response would be an array.